# One click EXE or autoit script to start an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, autoit

I know I can write an autoit or batch file, and it would be pretty easy, but does anyone know of a good one click executable to start an SSH tunnel? Ideally, I'd like to have a compilable autoit script that I could also include my key in (I would be the only one with a copy of this EXE, it's just nice and tidy to have a single exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (free, open-source, portable, Windows) as a [command line utility](http://etherealmind.com/putty-command-line/):

> putty.exe -ssh emind@198.18.14.9

You just need to add PuTTY to your Path:

[image]

[PuTTY Command Line Options](http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/faqs/others/putty/PuTTY%20Command%20Line%20Options.txt):

> 3.7.3.16 `-i': specify an SSH private key
>
> ```
>    The `-i' option allows you to specify the name of a private key file
>    in `*.'`PPK' format which PuTTY will use to authenticate with the
>    server. This option is only meaningful if you are using SSH.
>
>    For general information on public-key authentication, see chapter 8.
>
>    This option is equivalent to the `Private key file for
>    authentication' box in the Auth panel of the PuTTY configuration box
>    (see section 4.20.5).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I use bitvise ssh client with proxifier portable edition. (If you want I can give detailed instructions, but it should be pretty simple to figure out).

Comment: please "give detailed instructions" ...